# Can data be recovered from a deleted iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, backup

I'm creating an iOS app where people can store their data. I'm storing all user data encrypted locally on the device within the app.

1. If the user has iCloud backup enabled, will their encrypted data stored within the app get backed-up to iCloud?
2. If a user mistakenly deletes my app, did they lose all of their biometric data they had stored within my app or can they recover from a backup?

Comment: This is a very interesting question, but you could readily answer it yourself just by experimenting.

Comment: @matt I'm so early on in the creation of the app it's difficult to experiment at the moment. Plus, the question adds value to future users looking to know the same answer.

Comment: Uh-huh. Well, why don't you delete some _other_ app and see whether you can restore _its_ data from a backup?

Comment: Be aware, that iOS has device backup, not file backup; the user would need to restore their entire device to get their data back. If you think the data loss scenario is likely and a "bad thing" then you might want to provide some way for the user to export their data (although it is pretty difficult to delete an app from iOS by mistake). Also consider carefully whether you need encryption beyond that provided by iOS. Where is the key stored? Will that key be available when the user migrated to a new device?